# read external file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an external textfile of variable length named **profiles.txt** with information in the following format:

```
 Jason/Red/Tyrannosaurus
 Zack/Black/Mastodon
 Billy/Blue/Triceratops
 Trini/Yellow/Griffin
 (etc)
```

How can I read through the file using JavaScript to output the following HTML:

```
 Name: Jason<br>
 Color: Red<br>
 Avatar: Tyrannosaurus<br>
 <br>
 Name: Zack<br>
 Color: Black<br>
 Avatar: Mastodon<br>
 <br>
 (etc)
```

Comment: Where is the JavaScript running? From the browser?

Comment: javascript on the browser, external file is .txt file located on the same domain as the .html and javascript files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example using [**XMLHttpRequest**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest):

```
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('GET', "test.txt", false);
xmlhttp.send();
document.write(xmlhttp.responseText.split('\r\n').map(function (i) {return i.replace(/(.+),(.+),(.+)/g, 'Name: $1<br>Color: $2<br>Avatar: $3<br>')} ).join('<br/>'));
```

[**Array.map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) needs to be shim in IE8 and below. Also, IE uses `new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")`
This is a very slimmed down example. I'm using asyc false which is bad and document.write which is bad. But I just wanted to demonstrate getting the file and parsing the input.

Comment: This code would work to get the contents of a text file that is *on the server*. Valid code, yes, but I do not believe the file the OP is working with is located on the server - the word "external" in the question leads me to this conclusion.

Comment: @Chris, are you serious? Where is external? If it's not on the server, where is it? I guess, what I'm saying is why downvote me if you have no clue what the OP actually wants. That's cold

Comment: Who knows? I just noted that this code only applies if the file is on the server - is that true, or isn't it? I am not certain what aspect of this statement you find incredible. EDIT: Cool, OP specified that the file *is* on the server. Good deal. (FYI - no downvotes from me, man)

Comment: No sweat, have a +1 for penetrating the mist of vagary :)

Answer (score 5):

**ONLY APPLIES IF THE FILE IS NOT ALREADY ON THE SERVER** (not specified in question)

Without posting the file to the server or pasting the file's contents into a textbox, there is currently no way for javascript to interact directly with the file system.

Also for security reasons, javascript may not, by itself, look at the contents of a file that has been selected using a file-type input.

So, your options are:

- Upload the file to the server using AJAX-style form post, return the contents ([jQuery plugin for AJAX file uploads](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/))
- Submit the file via normal form postback, when the page is reloaded you can pass the contents along to javascript with JSON written to the output
- Copy/paste the data into a textarea, use an onKeyUp event to detect entry of data (or add a "Process" button) to read the textarea contents and go from there ([sample](http://jsfiddle.net/4zQAQ/))

Answer (score 0):

There is no file I/O in javascript for security reasons. Your best bet is to expose this text file in your server code and make an ajax call for it from the javascript

Answer (score -2):

```
var fileRead = "Jason,Red,Tyrannosaurus\nZack,Black,Mastodon\nBilly,Blue,Triceratops\nTrini,Yellow,Griffin";
var lines = fileRead.split("\n");

for (var i in lines){
    var pdata = lines[i].split(",");
    jQuery("#ResultDiv").append("Name: " + pdata[0] + "<br/>Color: " + pdata[1] + "<br/>Avatar: " + pdata[2] + "<br/><br/>" );
}
```