# Setting a javascript variable to an external markdown file

Tags: javascript, markdown

I have a long markdown file.  I also have a javascript file that runs a parser over markdown.  In my javascript file I have set:

var text = "md/markdown.md"

This does not seem to pull in the content of the markdown file as I would like it to.  However, if I copy and paste the contents of the markdown file into the variable, then everything works as it should.  Is there a way I can set this javascript variable to pick up the contents of this external markdown file?

Comment: Are you running a standalone Javascript interpreter, or are you running this in a web browser?

Comment: Under no circumstances does an assignment to a JavaScript variable trigger an HTTP request to load *anything*. (OK it would if you bound a setter to an ajax routine, but I don't think that's what we're talking about here :-)

Comment: He obviously does not understand that. I don't see how it's helpful to point it out, or how upvoting it does anything for anyone

Comment: @Pointy — `location = 'http://example.com/'` :)

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn it's a general clarification that the semantics of the language are fundamentally different than what's been assumed. The whole point of Stackoverflow is to have other people tell you what you've done wrong :-)

Comment: I'm running this in a web browser.  Realize this is probably an very dumb question but I just keep running up against a wall.  Trying to teach myself to program here!

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn — So we should only point things out to people if they *already* understand them? I think that is a bit backwards.

Comment: @Quentin you'd have to point that out wouldn't you :-)  In my defense I would say that `location` is not a JavaScript variable. It's a special property of the "native" `window` object.

Comment: @Pointy I'm not following.  I have called the script from my http file, so I think that takes care of loading it right?

Comment: @Jason the script is loaded, yes, but simply assigning the name of some file to a variable will not cause the browser to fetch that file. There's a mechanism to do that, but it involves explicit calls to an API (`XMLHttpRequest`).

Comment: @Pointy Ok that's helpful to know.  I guess my question would be what do I need to know to set a variable to the contents of an external file then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of a web browser, if you want JavaScript to fetch data from a URI then you will generally use the [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) object. MDN has a decent [tutorial about using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Most of the general purpose JavaScript libraries include wrappers for XHR that include compatibility fixes (especially for old-IE). I'm fond of [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/). Another option is the relatively ubiquitous [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

It isn't a problem for the case given in the question, but beware of [the same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 1):

Run an AJAX request:

```
var ajaxRequest, text;  

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        text = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've failed to check that the response had an OK status, set a URL to make the request to and to send the request. The comments are somewhat dated too, you mention some specific browsers, but not Chrome, and you don't mention that recent versions of IE have support for the standard XHR object.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript cannot directly read local files for security reason. As an alternative way, you can take use of `XMLHttpRequest` to achieve it. Please check the link on the stackoverflow: [read external file with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406209/read-external-file-with-javascript). In addition, HTML5 provides a standard way to interact with local files, via the [File API specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/). You may refer to the tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/